# How to create MS Excel file from grid with pages?

Tags: gridview, export-to-excel

We have ASP.NET application and should create MS Excel file from grid data. We don't need "SaveAs" dialog. The grid can be paged. Sometimes grid can have a lot of data in pages and it could be very slow to go through all of them.

How can we create MS Excel file from all data in grid in faster way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following article to create it http://dotnetask.com/Resource.aspx?Resourceid=644 . Even I know SpreadSheetgear company provides DLL to do so . Try to find more in codeplex , I think their also you can find couple of options. Check out this : http://npoi.codeplex.com/  and http://closedxml.codeplex.com/. Remember at the end of the day GridView is nothing than the collection of data so you can give the option to end use to download in excel in case you have so many pages of data

```
           ExportToExcel excel = new ExportToExcel();
           context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName + ".xls"));
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    context.Response.Write(excel.Excel(YOURCollection));
    context.Response.End();

   public class ExportToExcel
{
    public StringWriter Excel(MyCollection)
    {
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                Table table = new Table();
                TableRow tableRow = new TableRow();
                TableHeaderCell header;
                header = new TableHeaderCell();
                header.Text = "Receipt Id";
                header.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
                tableRow.Cells.Add(header);

                foreach (MyItem)
                {
                    TableRow row = new TableRow();
                    TableCell cell;
                    cell = new TableCell();
                    cell.Text = "" + MyItem.Info;
                    cell.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);

                    table.Rows.Add(row);
                }
                table.RenderControl(htw);
                return sw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to say it's ASP.NET application.

Comment: I have updated with my code that I am using in my project to export to excel . Formatting is very basic but it works

Comment: Thanks, but I need to create MS Excel file with all data from grid even if data in grid are paged.

Comment: I don't need "SaveAs" dialog. I just need to create MS Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple pages in your gridview I assume you have AllowPaging="True" on your .aspx page.

If you set that to to false when you call your function and then re-databind the gridview you wont have an issue with paging in the excel workbook.

So here my gridview is gvTest the code would look like this:

```
protected void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //exports gridview to Excel file.
     gvTest.AllowPaging = false;
     gvTest.DataBind();
     String filename;

     Response.Clear();

     filename = string.Format("WhateverFileNameYouWant.xls");

     Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", ("attachment; filename=" + filename));

     Response.ContentType = "application/excel";

     StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

     HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

     gvTest.RenderControl(htw);

     Response.Write(sw.ToString());

     Response.End();
 }
```

Also, if you receive an error on the gvTest.RenderControl(htw) line that might say something like this : "Control 'gvTest' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server."

you will most likely need to add:

```
 EnableEventValidation="false"
```

To the top of your .aspx page Where you will see "<%@ Page Language="C#"...."

and add:

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
 {
     return;
 }
```

Anywhere in your code behind.

This seems to be a common error.

Comment: If my answer helped anyone an up-vote would be nice and if not a down-vote seems deserving...